# Superclass constructors in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Scala's handling of superclass constructor parameters is confusing me...

with this code:

```
class ArrayElement(val contents: Array[String]) {
   ...
}

class LineElement(s: String) extends ArrayElement(Array(s)) {
  ...
}
```

LineElement is declared to extend ArrayElement, it seems strange to me that the `Array(s)` parameter in `ArrayElement(Array(s))` is creating an Array instance - runtime??? Is this scala's syntatic sugar or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the `Array(s)` expression is evaluated at run-time.

```
class Foo (val x: Int)
class Bar (x: Int, y: Int) extends Foo(x + y)
```

Scala allows expressions in the calls to a superclass' constructor (similar to what Java does with its use of `super(...)`). These expressions are evaluated at run-time.

Comment: I guess it is scala syntactic sugar then... things like: class LineElement(s: String) extends ArrayElement({ println(">> SubClass!"); Array(s)}) {...} is possible

Answer (score 2):

Actually The `Array(s)` is evaluated at run-time because the structure you've used is an effective call to primary constructor of your super class.

To recall, a class can only have on primary constructor that takes arguments in its definition `class A(param:AnyRef)`, other constructors are called `this` and are mandate to call the primary constructor (or to chain constructors up to it).

And, such a constraint exists on super call, that is, a sub class primary constructor calls the super primary constructor.

Here is how to see such Scala structure

```
class Foo (val x: Int)
class Bar (x: Int, y: Int) extends Foo(x + y)
```

the Java counterpart

```
public class Foo {
  private x:int;
  public Foo(x:int) {
    this.x = x;
  }
  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }
}

public class Bar {
  private y:int;

  public Bar(x:int, y:int) {
    /**** here is when your array will be created  *****/
    super(x+y); 
    this.y = y;
  }

    public int getY() {
    return y;
  }
}
```